# ASP.Net intelligent scaling page based on page content

Tags: c#, asp.net, scaling

Like iPhone Safari Browser or Firefox (Ctrl + Scrolling), I need intelligent scaling where not only Divs but also font-size and images are scaled based on the viewable area of the screen.

I need to implement this in ASP.Net. Any suggestion?

Regards
Thant Zin

Answer (score 0):

It's not a server side thing, its a presentation layer thing.  You need to look at using relative measurement sizes in CSS for applying the appropriate scaling. i.e, using percentages or ems, instead of pixels.

One thing you can do on the server side is browser-sniffing.  Find out what user agent your user is using, and then push that down with your page so you can apply the appropriate stylesheet where appropriate.

Comment: So, there is nothing we can do at .net side? In the mean time, I try to explore around and I came across this http://mdbf.codeplex.com/. I will read more about it.